# expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Tags: c++, class, compilation

```
#ifndef MAP_H_INCLUDED
#define MAP_H_INCLUDED

class Map()
{
public:
Map::Map();
Map::~Map();

unsigned int width,height;
Tile** mapTiles;
};

#endif
```

i'm just trying to declare a class, it worked fine a few minutes ago, now it just won't compile

Comment: If you used version control, you could just go back to see how it was when it was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be simply `Map()` and `~Map()`, not `Map::Map()` and `Map::~Map()`.

Oh, and it should be `class Map` not `class Map()`.

Comment: And you don't need the () after `class Map` either.

Comment: Did that, still same issue, the error is with the first line "class Map()"

Comment: Yeah, I missed that.  Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed solve it

Comment: @Zachcalhoun :  If you liked the answer, you should consider marking it as an "accepted answer."

Comment: I've been trying to do that for the past 6 minutes, i need to wait

Comment: @Zachcalhoun :  No worries.  I didn't realize SO put those sorts of timeouts in there.  Anyway, I was quite glad to help.  :-)